# windows.postMessage behaviour?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, postmessage

I need a cross domain call for sending a data to another server and get back same data to validate it, so for that I used window.postMessage with Iframe.

Its working fine.

I am sending a 1 MB string in message and get back from, so it is sending 1 MB string and receiving 1 MB string, this task completes in appx 4 SECs. I think this will not happens.

But When I used jsonp to download the same contents from same server using ajax jsonp, it takes 9 seconds.

So finally download only takes 9 secs and postmessage (send & response)  both takes 4 secs. How it possible ? I think its should be more than 9 seconds.

Please let me know why it happens.

Thanks,
Laxmilal Menaria